# File move is not working

Tags: java, maven

```
@RequestMapping("/XMLGenSuccess.json")
 public static String getXMLGenerationSuccess() {

    DBService dbService = new DBService();

    boolean success = false;
    try {

        DerivContactInfo contactInfo = dbService
                .DerivContactInfoService();
        Option option = dbService.BankReportService("fake bank");
        option.setinfo(contactInfo);


        File file = XMLgenService.buildXML(option);

        success = file.renameTo(new File("src/main/resources/Cache/report.xml"));

    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
if(success == true){
            return "True";
        }
        else{
            return "False";
        }

}

}
```

I have no idea why it doesn't work when i deploy server using maven. I made a seperate test class within the project and and yes it works and it drops the genereated xml in the directory i specfied.

Would any of you know the possible reason why this is not showing up, its just a blank page and no xml file is droped in the to the cache folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

... Because your web app doesn't know anything about your project's Maven directory layout.

`Cache/report.xml` is at the root of the classpath.

You're trying to rename something to something that exists *on the classpath*, which you cannot do.

A cache should not live within the web app itself, and in fact *can* not do so if you deploy as a war file. File caches should exist in a location external to the web app.

Comment: so would i be able to put it on my C drive?

Comment: @purplehaze You can put it anywhere your server can access.